# Find continuous dates in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

I am trying to solve one query which I have already solved in SQL Server.

> Write a SQL query to find continuous dates appear at least three times.

[SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8c46a7/3)

Table: `orders`

```
*------------*
|   mdate    |
*------------*
|'2012-05-01'|
|'2012-05-02'|
|'2012-05-03'|
|'2012-05-06'|
|'2012-05-07'|
|'2012-05-10'|
|'2012-05-11'|
*------------*
```

SQL Server:

```
select
  mdate
from
(
   select
      mdate,
      count(gap) over (partition by gap) as total
  from
  (
    select
      mdate,
      dateadd(day, - row_number() over (order by mdate), mdate) as gap
    from orders
  ) t
) tt

where total >= 3
```

Result:

```
*------------*
|   mdate    |
*------------*
|'2012-05-01'|
|'2012-05-02'|
|'2012-05-03'|
*------------*
```

I cannot use `dateadd()` function in PostgreSQL so how can I achieve same result in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server, this would look like:

```
select mdate
from (select o.*,
             count(*) over (partition by dateadd(day, - seqnum, mdate)) as cnt
      from (select o.*,
                   row_number() over (order by mdate) as seqnum
            from orders o
           ) o
     ) o
where cnt >= 3;
```

In Postgres:

```
select mdate
from (select o.*,
             count(*) over (partition by mdate - seqnum * interval '1 day') as cnt
      from (select o.*,
                   row_number() over (order by mdate) as seqnum
            from orders o
           ) o
     ) o
where cnt >= 3;
```

The only difference is the date arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

You can make an interval out of your `ROW_NUMBER` computation by `CONCAT` with `' day'` and typecasting; then you can subtract that from `mdate`. Your query remains the same other than changing

```
dateadd(day, - row_number() over (order by mdate), mdate) as gap
```

to

```
mdate - concat(row_number() over (order by mdate), ' day')::interval as gap
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/8c46a/2)